# getting the source code of remote page then display only one div based on its id

Tags: php, file-get-contents

exactly as its descriped in the title currently my code is:

```
<?php
    $url = "remotesite.com/page1.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

?>
```

my coding skills are very basic so at this point i am lost and dont know how to display only the div that has the id `id=mydiv`

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP 5.3.6 or higher you can do the following:

```
$url = "remotesite.com/page1.html";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html
$testElement = $doc->getElementById('divIDName');
echo $doc->saveHTML($testElement);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

If you have a lower version I believe you would need to copy the Dom node once you found it with getElementById into a new DomDocument object.

```
$elementDoc = new DOMDocument();
$cloned = $testElement->cloneNode(TRUE);
$elementDoc->appendChild($elementDoc->importNode($cloned,TRUE));
echo $elementDoc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: thanks for your help but in your 1st code the variable `$levi` is undefined and the code doesn't work and yes i have php 5.4.7

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I had been testing using dummy variables and missed updating it. That $levi var should have been $testElement.